# How to bind StringProperty to ObjectProperty<Integer> in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding

I found only solution how to bind StringProperty to IntegerProperty, something like this:

```
StringProperty.bindBidirectional(IntegerProperty, new NumberStringConverter());
```

But I need also `null` value. How to bind `StringProperty to ObjectProperty<Integer>`?

Comment: @CloseVoter Could you explain the reason to vote to close? If this is stupid qustion, just explain, I will delete it myself not to disturb community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default `IntegerStringConverter` understand nulls:

```
ObjectProperty<Integer> objP = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
stringProp.bindBidirectional(objP, new IntegerStringConverter());

objP.setValue(null); // stringProp == ""
stringProp.setValue(""); // objP == null
```

If you want different behaviour you can make your own converter:

```
    ObjectProperty<Integer> objP = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    stringProperty.bindBidirectional(objP, new StringConverter<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Integer number) {
            return number == null ? "NULL" : number.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public Integer fromString(String string) {
            return string.equals("NULL") ? null : Integer.valueOf(string); 
        }
    });

    // both works:
    objP.setValue(null);
    objP.setValue(100);
```

Comment: Should be `number.toString()`